# Typescript generic picking up wrong type

Tags: typescript, generics, polymorphism, subclass

Lets say I have four classes:
`A` with a generic `T` and `B` which specifies the generic `T` as `X`.
The last class is `Y` which extends `X` with a new property `baz`.

```js
class A<T> {
  foo: T;
}

class B extends A<X> {}

class X {}

class Y extends X {
  baz: string;
}

// works!
new B().foo = new Y()
```

Now I want to have make a function which type-safe assigns a value to `foo`:

```js
function test<T, V extends A<T>>(t: T, v: V) {
  v.foo = t;
}
```

This function takes the value for `foo`(`t`) and the instance of `A` or a subclass of it (`v`) and assigns the value to it's `foo` property.
However if I want to assign a instance of `Y` to a instance of `B` I get an error:

```js
// Typescript error: Property 'baz' is missing in type 'X' but required in type 'Y'.
test(new Y(), new B());
```

This is where I am stuck.
How can I make typescript pick up the correct types for the generics of the `test` function.
What should happen is that typescript understands that `B` requires `foo` to be an instance of `X` and therefore assigning a `Y` instance to it should not be an issue.

Many thanks for any advice on improving my typings.

Comment: I think you'll have to make `B` generic: https://tsplay.dev/wEpVbW

Comment: Do any of [these approaches](https://tsplay.dev/mZJ89m) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @kelsny looks like its working, but I was hoping that I don't have to change the signature of `B` (as `B` should to care that a subclass of `X` is assigned to `foo`).

Comment: @jcalz You examples are to restrictive for me. They don't work once the classes become more complex.

Comment: Without a [mre] I don't know what else to suggest; could you [edit] the code in the question to provide one that demonstrates "they don't work"?

Comment: @jcalz I think I have provided the minimal reproducible example. I just cannot work with a solution where I explicitly have to select the property (e.g. `foo`) in order to make typescript accept the types because in my real world use case this will be (too) many properties.

Comment: If you're not willing to do as I asked then I'll just disengage so that others can help if they're able. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the exact requirement of your use-case, [here](https://tsplay.dev/m3VzEN)'s how you can constraint your generics -

```ts
class A<T> {
    foo!: T;
}

class B extends A<X> { }

class X { }

class Y extends X {
    baz!: string;
}

// works!
new B().foo = new Y()

function test<U extends X, T extends U, V extends A<U>>(t: T, v: V) {
    v.foo = t;
}

test(new Y(), new B());
```